# Prove, If the sum of the first $n$ prime is also a prime then it is also a hypotenuse of a primitive Pythagorean triples

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, prime-numbers

I checked this for all the primitive Pythagorean triples $<300$.

Some examples would be: 
                                        a. $2+3=5$, 
                                      b. $2+3+5+7=17$, 
                                   c. $2+3+5+7+11+13=41$, 
                             d. $2+3+5+7+11+13+17+19+23+29+31+37=197$

Any kind proof and insight will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This is false. [Euclid’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) shows that a number is the hypotenuse of a primitive Pythagorean triple if and only if it can be written as the sum of two squares. [Fermat proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) that an odd prime can be written as the sum of two squares if and only if it’s $1 \pmod 4$. But the sum of the first $60$ primes is $7699$, which is a prime that’s $3 \pmod 4$. (This is the smallest counterexample; see [A013918](http://oeis.org/A013918) for a list of sums of primes that are prime.)

Answer (score 1):

The standard formula for generating all primitive pythagorean triples is

a=m^2-k^2, b=2km, c=k^2+m^2; c^2=a^2+b^2

where k,m are integers with k in (0,m), gcd(k,m)=1, and either 2 dividing k or 2 dividing m, but not both. Thus, show that your number x which is the sum of the first n primes and prime itself can be written in the form of c, and that there exist numbers(construct them) of the form a and b subject to those constraints. It would be easier to do a couple examples first to get a notion for the flow of the proof. Finally, use induction on n.

Comment: Maybe add that for a prime to be $k^2+m^2$ one needs the prime to be $4t+1.$ It doesn't seem immediately obvious (at least to me) that all the partial sums of the primes are of this form provided they are prime.

Comment: @coffeemath That is an excellent point.

Comment: Indeed, is there some lemma that a sum of sequential prime numbers is a sum of squares if it is prime?  That seems to be the most important part of the question.

Comment: Note: by induction on n, I mean induction on n as the length of the sum yielding a prime output.

Comment: @DanielV I have no clue about the technical details, I only meant to give an outline of proof. But, if the OP's premise is true then there definitely is. And, that is indeed the direction of thought I was intending with the outline.